# Keycloak - How to request a token with a custom lifespan?

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, keycloak

**Context:** We are using Keycloak to secure our APIs by usually passing tokens through Authorization Headers. However, these APIs also allow users to download files (for instance: `https://api.service.io/users.xlsx`).

To use these "download endpoints", our web client applications pass users' token via query strings. (*e.g.* `https://api.service.io/users.xlsx?accessToken=${bearerToken})`).

**Problem:** Passing tokens via query string has several security flaws (browser history, ...). Therefore we would like to pass a very short-lived token (*e.g.* lifespan of 15sec) instead of the normal one (lifespan of 300sec by default).

**Question:** How could we request a different token from Keycloak API (for instance, `/realms/#{realm_id}/protocol/openid-connect/token`) by:

- providing the normal access token (not credentials);
- *and* specifying a different lifespan ?

Comment: Did you even go through documentation ? http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_timeouts

Comment: Sending access in query string is bad. Why not use a header. When you get SSL, you get encrpyion. Access logs won't reveal them too

Comment: I've read the documentation, indeed. I can change the **default** lifespan using the Admin API, but that's not the point. I want to keep this default lifespan for most tokens. However, I want the capability to specify a different lifespan when requesting specific tokens. About your second comment, you can't always use Headers. For example, when you redirect browsers to a download link, you can't.

Comment: okay, now only I understood your requirement. And for the second point, you might use a form submission on page load (but will depend on exact scenario). For the original question, can't you specificy scope value in auth req and restrict access tokens access level ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading Keycloak's source code, it appears this is not possible (version `3.4.2.Final`) to ask for a specific lifespan at runtime.

However, I developed a Keycloak Custom REST endpoint to do that. https://github.com/looorent/keycloak-configurable-token-api

When this JAR file is deployed in Keycloak, you can ask for a given lifespan at runtime. For example:

`$ curl -X POST -d '{ "tokenLifespanInSeconds": 20}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <user-access-token>" http://auth.service.io/auth/realms/a-realm/configurable-token`

Answer (score 1):

For someone looking for a way to get a permanent token for internal usage (or any usage), without using any external jar, there is a workaround.

1. Create a client and enable client-credentials for that client: Enable `client-authentication` and `client-authorization`.
2. For that client, remember the client-id and client-secret, then send the following request to keycloak:

   ```
   curl --location 'https://my.keycloak.url/realms/realm-name/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
   --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
   --data-urlencode 'client_id=my-client-id' \
   --data-urlencode 'client_secret=my-client-secret' \
   --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
   ```

   This will return you a json with `access_token`.
3. Use this access token.
4. In case you wish to have a set of `roles` assigned to this token, just go to your client and click on the `Service account roles` tab. Here you can add one or more roles to this client. Any further token request will provide you with a token with the assigned roles.

---

Note that although this access token is time limited and will expire soon, you can always get a new token directly via the API call mentioned in step 2. So no human intervention involved.