# How to set a specific session idle timeout for a token in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am developing a solution using Keycloak.
My system has one realm and the tenants are determined by the groups.
It's a hard restriction to also use one client to authenticate the users so the multi client idea went out the window.
The idea is to have a controllable session idle timeout based on the group the user belongs to or a user attribute.

I saw this solution to control the token expiry in the set claim.
However I could not find a way to manipulate the session idle timeout or refresh token expiry from it only the token expiry.
[How to provide custom expiration for each access token in keycloak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76537345/how-to-provide-custom-expiration-for-each-access-token-in-keycloak/76563046#76563046)

I tried to see if I could override TokenManager.java or AuthenticationToken.java to be able to insert some custom logic there but also failed.

It tried listening to the refresh token events and killing the sessions from it. But since this happens asynchronisly it also not a valid solution.